# Property 'currentUser' does not exist on type 'FirebaseAuthState'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

trying to get currentUser in angularfire2. what type exposes this?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

it's not obvious to me from exploring this observable:

```
constructor(private auth: FirebaseAuth) {
  auth.subscribe((user) => console.log('user is', user));    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user` object that I receive from the `FirebaseAuth` observable contains the following properties:

- `provider`
- `uid`
- `auth`

The last of these - `auth` - is the `currentUser`. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth_backend.ts#L42-L52), you can see that the `auth` property is a Firebase `User`.

You can verify this using `instanceof`:

```
constructor(private auth: FirebaseAuth) {
    auth.subscribe(
        (user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log('user.auth is a User instance = ' + (currentUser instanceof firebase.User));
                let currentUser = user.auth;
                // ...
            } else {
                console.log('no user signed in');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks. the thing that is missing is the updateProfile method. but, i don't see that in the auth_backend.ts source either.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Comment: and i guess this is the answer. should have googled better. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/281

Comment: The `user.auth` property is a `User` instance, so it has the `updateProfile` method. That is, you can call `user.auth.updateProfile(...)`. If you are looking at the `user.auth` in the console, it might not be obvious that the `updateProfile` method is there, as it's in the prototype.

Comment: It would have been a lot less confusing if they'd named it `currentUser` instead of `auth`.

Comment: thanks @cartant. you're right. i was thrown off as vscode had a red squiggle under "updateProfile" and warned: [ts] 
Property 'updateProfile' does not exist on type 'User'.
any